# Find Largest Directories/Files when Drive is Full

Tags: disk, disk-usage, storage, du

When the drive of an Ubuntu 20.04 server is full, how can we find out the directories/files with the largest sizes, ranked from largest to smallest? This can allow me to find some files to delete (likely log files)

Tried installing `ncdu` but theres insufficient space

```
# sudo apt install ncdu
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Tried `du` with `sort` but it cant run with no disk space left.

```
# du --max-depth=7 /* | sort -n 
sort: write failed: /tmp/sort5SKbZn: No space left on device
```

**`df -h` Output**:

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            474M     0  474M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M   11M   88M  12% /run
/dev/vda1        25G   25G     0 100% /
tmpfs           491M   40K  491M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           491M     0  491M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2066
/dev/loop2       68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/20326
/dev/vda15      105M  7.9M   97M   8% /boot/efi
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/0
overlay          25G   25G     0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/183819e24cd73185c27ef0af229e31e909f4af51dd7a4e0178eeab68a2f924e1/merged
/dev/loop3       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12398
/dev/loop4       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
shm              64M   16K   64M   1% /var/lib/docker/containers/fdcf13f925676b32eaac67a55ff245d4ed7f0c91c78db26169106af56b15e77f/mounts/shm
/dev/loop5       71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21029
/dev/loop6       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12704
```

Comment: `sudo apt clean` is a good first step. `mc` can help you too, it can calculate directory sizes.

Answer (score 2):

If you can `ssh` from a different machine, then you can pipe the output to `sort` on the machine that is not full. Let's say that you have two machines -- `slim` (which doesn't have a full hard drive) and `full`, which does.

From the command prompt on `slim`:

```
ssh user@full 'du -sh /' | sort -h
```

The first part:

```
ssh user@full 'du -sh /'
```

generates output from `full`. The pipeline `| sort -h` is running *locally* on `slim`, so you won't get errors about disk space.

Comment: Nifty idea! Trying it out